# Scroll UICollectionView by pixels or percent?

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview

Fairly simple question, but I'm having a surprisingly hard time finding an answer: is it possible to scroll a UICollectionView by anything other than the indexPath of a cell within the view?

I've got this right now, in order to center a cell onscreen:

```
[_mainCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
[_mainCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
```

...but I'd love to be able to tell it "scroll 40% to the right" or "scroll 100 pixels down", regardless of what cell is at that position.

This seems like it MUST exist, but I just can't find it.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so maybe you can use the method of `UIScrollView` to achieve what you want

> setContentOffset:animated:
>
> scrollRectToVisible:animated: